# Chaining re.sub() without breaking previous re.sub() - python

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution

I have a file like this:

```
(a) a. lo mfana
(20) Juan - il- -ech (lik) !
EB1: Incwadi [esi-yi-funda-yo: isitshudeni] in-de
Papa-wu-rna parlapiya-nyi paja-lkura.
b) kupi-Nku Nia taca-mu
i. gaan1 fong2 hak1 maa1 maa1, nei5 dim2 tai2 dou2 syu1 gaa3 i. 
4. a. ngo5 lou5gung1 ci3ci3 faan1lei4. dou1 haak1 saai3 gam2
(n-ngwathel-l-e )
M: sik6-saai3 laa3!   (17)
U3 :      O?i=j se-si-ni           duy-ur-am-yor-du (17)
```

And I want to remove the bullets-like substring at the start of the string. These bullets are either enclosed in rounded brackets of start with a maximum of 3 alphanumeric character(s) and end with either a `.` , `)` or `:`.

The desired output is:

```
a. lo mfana
Juan - il- -ech (lik) !
Incwadi [esi-yi-funda-yo: isitshudeni] in-de
Papa-wu-rna parlapiya-nyi paja-lkura.
kupi-Nku Nia taca-mu
gaan1 fong2 hak1 maa1 maa1, nei5 dim2 tai2 dou2 syu1 gaa3 i. 
a. ngo5 lou5gung1 ci3ci3 faan1lei4. dou1 haak1 saai3 gam2
(n-ngwathel-l-e )
sik6-saai3 laa3!   (17)
O?i=j se-si-ni           duy-ur-am-yor-du (17)
```

I've been doing it as such but my regexes. But i fail because:

- Using **`src = re.sub(r'\([^)]*\)', '', src)`**, I was removing more than the heading `(...)`

  **[in]:** (20) Juan - il- -ech (lik) !

  **[out]:** Juan - il- -ech !

  **[need]:** Juan - il- -ech (lik) !
- Using **`src = re.sub(r'^\([^)]*\)', '', src)`**, I was able to specify the start of line with `^` in the regex but it didn't get the maximum of 3 alphanumeric condition.

  **[in]:** (n-ngwathel-l-e )

  **[out]:**

  **[need]:** (n-ngwathel-l-e )

  **[in]:** U3 :      O?i=j se-si-ni           duy-ur-am-yor-du (17)

  **[out]:**

  **[need]:** O?i=j se-si-ni           duy-ur-am-yor-du (17)
- Using **`re.sub(r'^:[^)]*\)', '',src)` and `re.sub(r'^\.[^)]*\)', '',src)`**, I was not able to make the regex detect `[0-9a-zA-z][0-9a-zA-z][0-9a-zA-z]` followed by a `.` or `:`

  **[in]:** 4. a. ngo5 lou5gung1 ci3ci3 faan1lei4. dou1 haak1 saai3 gam2

  **[out]:** 4. a. ngo5 lou5gung1 ci3ci3 faan1lei4. dou1 haak1 saai3 gam2

  **[need]:** a. ngo5 lou5gung1 ci3ci3 faan1lei4. dou1 haak1 saai3 gam2

  **[in]:** EB1: Incwadi [esi-yi-funda-yo: isitshudeni] in-de

  **[out]:** EB1: Incwadi [esi-yi-funda-yo: isitshudeni] in-de

  **[need]:** Incwadi [esi-yi-funda-yo: isitshudeni] in-de

**How should I form a single regex / chain of regex substitutions such that i don't break the other regex conditions for other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

```
^\(?\w{1,3}\s*[):.]\s*
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regexr.com?37j1p

#### Discussion

I'll take each of your regexes and output the problem in each:

*1. Using src = re.sub(r'([^)]*)', '', src), I was removing more than the heading (...)*

The `*` quantifier is greedy. It will try to the **most possible** characters that are not `)`. This is why you get more than the heading.

*2. Using `src = re.sub(r'^\([^)]*\)', '', src)`, I was able to specify the start of line with ^ in the regex but it didn't get the maximum of 3 alphanumeric condition.*

The `*` quantifier means `zero or more`. If you want 3 alphanumeric max, you need to use this quantifier: `{1,3}`. It means 1, 2 or three times.

*3.Using re.sub(r'^:[^)]*)', '',src) and re.sub(r'^.[^)]*)', '',src), I was not able to make the regex detect [0-9a-zA-z][0-9a-zA-z][0-9a-zA-z] followed by a . or :*

Here the regex is missing the `.` and `:` for matching those characters respectively.